# Need solutions to minimize memory allocation

Tags: go, garbage-collection, circular-buffer

I have the following code, the flush func below uses 1 allocation per call which copies all data and returns. Are there any other more performant solutions resulting in less garbage collection and fewer CPU cycles?

Can we use sync.Pool here? If so then how? Event slice could be up to 10k elements.

```
type collector struct {
    sync.Mutex
    count int
    events []*event 
}

type event struct {
    name string
}

func New() *collector {
    return &collector{
        count: 0,
        event: make([]*event,10000),
}

func (c *collector) add(e *event) {
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    c.events[c.count + 1] = e
    c.count++
}

func (c *collector) flush() []*event{
    c.Lock()
    defer c.Unlock()
    result := make([]*event, c.count)
    copy(result, c.events)
    c.count = 0
    return result
}
```

Comment: Can the result of each call to `flush` be kept and referenced indefinitely? Because in that case you do need a separate slice to hold the events. If however only the result of most recent `flush` call is required, you can try using a circular queue, returning re-sliced `c.events` instead of creating new slices.

Comment: Aside: If you decide to stick with the copy, you can get rid of the count field if you leverage slice capacities: https://play.golang.org/p/tfKqCUZW0z. Fixes a potential index-out-of-range panic in add() along the way.